# How can I pass a payload which is an object to consume a web-service SOAP in Mule?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, mule

I want to consume a SOAP webservice using Mule, but I can not pass the parameter in the payload that for what I understand is an object of class ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTA, but is giving the following message:
argument type mismatch. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: Class

**How to pass the correct parameter via payload or another way that works?**

**Follows the flow**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.4.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="Bean" name="Bean" class="sap.bapi.fornecedor.ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTA"/>
    </spring:beans>
    <flow name="sap6Flow1" doc:name="sap6Flow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-payload value="#[sap.bapi.fornecedor.ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTA]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA" clientClass="sap.bapi.fornecedor.ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService" port="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAPortType" doc:name="SOAP"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

**Follows the wsdl:**

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:s0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
<xsd:element name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:all/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA.Response">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:all>
<xsd:element name="LISTA">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="s0:ZSDE002"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="ZSDE002">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="LIFNR" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="NAME1" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:maxLength value="35"/>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAInput">
<part name="parameters" element="s0:ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA"/>
</message>
<message name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAOutput">
<part name="parameters" element="s0:ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA.Response"/>
</message>
<portType name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAPortType">
<operation name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA">
<input message="s0:ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAInput"/>
<output message="s0:ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAOutput"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTABinding" type="s0:ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAPortType">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.sap.com/ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAService">
<documentation>SAP Service ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA via SOAP</documentation>
<port name="ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAPortType" binding="s0:ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTABinding">
<soap:address location="url service"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

**Follows the service class:**

```
package sap.bapi.fornecedor;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.WebEndpoint;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceClient;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;

/**
 * SAP Service ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA via SOAP
 *
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.5.1
 * 2014-05-05T09:01:25.221-03:00
 * Generated source version: 2.5.1
 * 
 */
@WebServiceClient(name = "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAService", 
                  wsdlLocation = ".../wsdl11.services_zrfc_funcionario_lista.wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions") 
public class ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions", "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAService");
    public final static QName ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType = new QName("urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions", "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAPortType");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(".../wsdl11.services_zrfc_funcionario_lista.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                     "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", ".../wsdl11.services_zrfc_funcionario_lista.wsdl");
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }

    public ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService(URL wsdlLocation) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE);
    }

    public ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    public ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService() {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE);
    }

    //This constructor requires JAX-WS API 2.2. You will need to endorse the 2.2
    //API jar or re-run wsdl2java with "-frontend jaxws21" to generate JAX-WS 2.1
    //compliant code instead.
    public ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService(WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE, features);
    }

    //This constructor requires JAX-WS API 2.2. You will need to endorse the 2.2
    //API jar or re-run wsdl2java with "-frontend jaxws21" to generate JAX-WS 2.1
    //compliant code instead.
    public ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService(URL wsdlLocation, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, SERVICE, features);
    }

    //This constructor requires JAX-WS API 2.2. You will need to endorse the 2.2
    //API jar or re-run wsdl2java with "-frontend jaxws21" to generate JAX-WS 2.1
    //compliant code instead.
    public ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName, WebServiceFeature ... features) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     *     returns ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAPortType")
    public ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType getZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType() {
        return super.getPort(ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType, ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType.class);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param features
     *     A list of {@link javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature} to configure on the proxy.  Supported features not in the <code>features</code> parameter will have their default values.
     * @return
     *     returns ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType
     */
    @WebEndpoint(name = "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAPortType")
    public ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType getZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType(WebServiceFeature... features) {
        return super.getPort(ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType, ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType.class, features);
    }

}
```

**class port:**

```
package sap.bapi.fornecedor;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.5.1
 * 2014-05-05T09:01:25.210-03:00
 * Generated source version: 2.5.1
 * 
 */
@WebService(targetNamespace = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions", name = "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAPortType")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
public interface ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType {

    @WebResult(name = "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA.Response", targetNamespace = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions", partName = "parameters")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA", action = "http://www.sap.com/ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA")
    public ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAResponse zrfcFUNCIONARIOLISTA(
        @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA", targetNamespace = "urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions")
        ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTA parameters
    );
}
```

**And client class:**

```
package sap.bapi.fornecedor;

/**
 * Please modify this class to meet your needs
 * This class is not complete
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.5.1
 * 2014-05-05T09:01:25.082-03:00
 * Generated source version: 2.5.1
 * 
 */
public final class ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType_ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType_Client {

    private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions", "ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTAService");

    private ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType_ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType_Client() {
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws java.lang.Exception {
        URL wsdlURL = ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService.WSDL_LOCATION;
        if (args.length > 0 && args[0] != null && !"".equals(args[0])) { 
            File wsdlFile = new File(args[0]);
            try {
                if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
                    wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
                } else {
                    wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService ss = new ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
        ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType port = ss.getZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAPortType();  

        {
        System.out.println("Invoking zrfcFUNCIONARIOLISTA...");
        sap.bapi.fornecedor.ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTA _zrfcFUNCIONARIOLISTA_parameters = null;
        sap.bapi.fornecedor.ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTAResponse _zrfcFUNCIONARIOLISTA__return = port.zrfcFUNCIONARIOLISTA(_zrfcFUNCIONARIOLISTA_parameters);
        System.out.println("zrfcFUNCIONARIOLISTA.result=" + _zrfcFUNCIONARIOLISTA__return);


        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the flow where you the SOAP service?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the intention with the Spring bean: you want to instantiate a new `sap.bapi.fornecedor.ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTA` per request so you don't really need a bean.

You have to use the `new` keyword in MEL to instantiate the request object:

```
<set-payload value="#[new sap.bapi.fornecedor.ZRFCFUNCIONARIOLISTA()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Note that I don't think that's enough: I reckon you have properties to set on this object to form a valid request. You can expand the MEL expression with calls to the setters to do so.

Comment: I tried and did not work, same error. I was trying to instantiate because I thought it was the correct parameter, and also tried just did not work.
<set-payload value="#[{' ', ' '}]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

I am not knowing what lay parameter by payload

Comment: and is changed by returning an empty response

<expression-transformer expression="#[new sap.bapi.fornecedor.ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA()]" doc:name="Expression"/>

Response:
<ns2:ZRFC_FUNCIONARIO_LISTA.Response xmlns:ns2="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions"/>

Error:
No common Object of type 'class javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext' configured